# Box Shadow Cut off

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, emotion

I have a container that lists some cards (divs). This container is a grid element with 2 columns
The CSS for the container element is below.

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 350px);
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
  gap: 1.75rem 3rem;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;

  // This is needed to display the box-shadows since overflow is set
  padding: 10px;
  margin: -10px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  height: 450px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Each card element (the element with a box-shadow) is wrapped in a div that extends its height by 16px

```
const Wrapper = styled(Box)`
  height: calc(100% + 16px);
`;
```

This seems to fix the box-shadow being cut off, but the `height: 450px` does not work across every browser as it appears inconsistent. I'm trying to arrive at a solution where the height of the card container (which is the scrolling container, code below) is only say 12px from the bottom so that this hacky solution can be avoided.

I'm not quite able to understand why the box-shadow at the bottom is cut off though.

[image: box shadow cut off]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 350px);
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
  gap: 1.75rem 3rem;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  
  padding: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  margin: -10px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  height: 450px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.card {
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 350px;
  height: 245px;
  
  box-shadow:
    -5px -5px 10px 0px white,
    10px 10px 15px 0px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: by adding padding to the the parent element of the cards will help you out here.

Comment: If you notice, the parent already has a padding-bottom of 10px to it. It does not work despite that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution on your query.

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 450px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 350px);
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
  gap: 1.75rem 3rem;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  margin: -10px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.card {
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  width: 350px;
  height: 245px;
  box-shadow: -5px -5px 10px 0px white, 10px 10px 15px 0px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to calc the height: 450 to be more semantic? It would be actually idea if the height is 100% and the overflowing content is scrollable. Any idea?

Comment: height is just used to show an example you can remove height and make it 100% it will still work the same.